# How to use list_pop?

Tags: zapier

This is related to the Zapier Python code. Has anyone been successful using the `pop_list()` function as part of the [StoreClient library](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#store-state)? I'm stuck on this simple program. Basically i'm trying to remove the first item in my list that is stored in MyList.get('MyIDList')

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is my code. Note if I remove the 2nd line, it'll work fine. My list is certainly not empty.

```
MyList= StoreClient('STSecretKey')

MyList.list_pop('MyIDList', location='head')

return {'FirstItem':MyList.get('MyIDList')[0]}
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/tmpPToKk0/usercode.py", line 9, in the_function

    MyList.list_pop('MyIDList', location='head')

  File "/var/task/store_api.py", line 226, in list_pop

    return self.call('patch', BASE_URL, json=data)

  File "/var/task/store_api.py", line 61, in call

    raise StoreCallException(json['error'])

StoreCallException: list is empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong, but my best guess is that your list isn't actually a list. You can quickly verify this by going to https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=STSecretKey, which shows the JSON that's stored in the database. If it's correct, it'll look like this:

```
{
  "MyIDList": {
    "list": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

To generate the above, I ran the following code:

```py
store = StoreClient('davidkey')

store.list_push('MyIDList', 1)
store.list_push('MyIDList', 2)
store.list_push('MyIDList', 3)

popped = store.list_pop('j', location='head')  # got 1
accessed = store.get('j')[0]  # got error
```

You'll notice that the last line generated an error for me. Given that it works for you (but popping off the list doesn't), I'm guessing that you instead have a key of `0` that has data in it. If you make sure to use `list_push` to populate your storage, it should work as expected.

Comment: My problem was indeed incorrect assignment of the list. Thank you so much.