# Take all data from Zapier Storage

Tags: zapier

I need to get all the data from StoreClient (Javascript). The format of the data on the below picture, they are in Zapier Storage.

```js
const store = StoreClient('mysecret');
const value = await store.getMany('mykey'); // or store.get('mykey') 
return {result: value}
```

This code works well. But I need to take and process all stored keys in a loop along with all their child value. I did not find a way :(

I tried **store.list_pop(key)**, but the lists have a different storage format. And the data is not retrieved.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Zapier's storage API which will allow you to retrieve all stored data through a GET request to https://store.zapier.com/api/records. I often have to do the same thing and this works for me.

Have a look at their documentation [here](https://store.zapier.com/?_ga=2.126577157.946586779.1544661935-996614246.1543893748). I typically code in Python using the requests library. But I'm sure you could achieve similar results using an ajax or fetch request in Javascript.

**EDIT**

If I am understanding your question correctly you are trying to 'GET' all of your data stored in Zapier's storage client. As per their API documentation:

[image: Zapier store API GET documentation]

Zapier stores your data as a dictionary object which can hold key value pairs. Those values can also be nested dictionaries or lists. Regardless of how you store the data (simple key value pairs, nested lists, nested dictionaries, or some combination of the preceding) a 'GET' request will return the entire object. As stated before I typically use Python's request library to handle HTTP requests but I was able to achieve the same result using a Javascript fetch request. I setup a dummy storage account at https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=dog to test and illustrate how this works. See my code below.

```
var url = "https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=dog";
const res = await fetch(url);
const body = await res.json()
return {JSON : body}
```

Unfortunately, due to my lack of familiarity with Javascript I had to bake the secret into the url, which I don't think is ideal, but for the purposes of this example it does the job. See my output below.

[image]

As you can see the 'GET' request returned all data stored in my Zapier storage account. I simply returned the data I retrieved from the 'GET' request but you could of course loop through the results and execute logic as needed. This does not modify any of the data stored, what I often do is pull in all of my stored date with a 'GET' request, modify it, delete the old storage, and 'POST' my modified storage information. This allows me to limit my requests to two calls rather than modifying each individual value.

Comment: Thanks! I know about this URL (https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=test). But I do not really understand how I can get this data from the step 'Zapier code'.  As a result, I need to somehow get an array or collection from this API request. I would be very grateful for any sample code or link.

_If someone reads this question, then the secret parameter should be subjected to URI-encoding. Those. link https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=ab#cd - will not work, but https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=ab%23cd - will work successfully._

Comment: I looked at all the documentation and answers here, but did not find the appropriate methods of object StoreClient. I found an unofficial description of this object only here: https://github.com/whieronymus/Py-Zap-Tester/blob/master/src/zap.py

The only method to get multiple objects I found is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420573/how-to-use-list-pop This is @xavdid answer, but there is a little about something else. Unable to get child object values.

Comment: I thought it was a very common usage pattern. You collect data in one Zapier storage from different zaps during the day. And then from one zap you process all the previously saved data. If the "Zapier code" block returns an array, then all subsequent zap steps are performed for each object in the array. At least that is how it should work. But I stumbled on the first part of the task, get all the data from the storage at the "Zapier code" step.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that this is exactly what I need. I did not know how to execute this GET-request from the Zapier. You helped me a lot! Happy New Year! )))